# Node+Express+Jade : Array/Objects Not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

//What I am passing in [currently] to the Jade template

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    res.render('report', {title: 'Custom Reports', 
        rpts:[{uri:'/reports/allocation', title:'Allocation Report'}]});
};
```

//The Jade template

```
 extends layout 
    h1 title
    ul
        each rpt in rpts
        li= a(href=rpt.uri)= rpt.title
```

//I see the title written in the head, but the body is empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Custom Reports</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body></body></html>
```

//If I remove the template extenstion, I get an error on the page

TypeError: /views/report.jade:5 3| h1 title 4| ul > 5| each rpt in rpts 6| li=   a(href=rpt.uri)= rpt.title Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

it might be your formatting here in Stack, but the li tag shoudl be indented under the each declaration.  Also you don't need the second = sign after the anchor.

```
each rpt in rpts
  li= a(href=rpt.uri) rpt.title
```

UPDATED
Oh, and I just noticed you're missing the `block` directive for your content.  Whatever `block` you declared in your layout should be placed here for rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I caught that too.  I am still getting the same error when I try and pass the rpts via render().  When I add the JSON array of objects directly into the template, the template works as expected.